# What is the correct shortened form for "Goals of the Theses"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

What is the correct shortening for "Goals of the Theses"?

1. Theses Goals
2. Theses' Goals

I am confused, because *Theses* ends with an 's', but using the apostrophe makes it plural.

Comment: It is common practice to omit the possessive -- and is permitted. "Theses Goals" = "Theses' Goals" where required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thesis* is singular, *theses* is plural. *Thesis'* is singular genitive, *theses'* is plural genitive. As a general rule for genitives of words ending in *s*, you use *s'*, the Saxon genitive.

So, assuming you want to talk about the multiple goals in multiple theses, then you would use "theses' goals". If you want to talk about multiple goals on a single thesis, you would use "thesis' goals."

As a general rule you can translate "x of the y" into "y's x", these being the two forms of genitive in English. However, beware, there are many instances where the two are not interchangeable.

Comment: In the case of singular nouns ending in -s, often just the apostrophe is added, but this is generally discouraged - see https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/ or many other references for that. So **thesis's** is the correct version for the singular form.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Thesis** is the singular form, and **theses** is the plural. If you have one thesis, you can say **thesis's goals**, but **goals of the thesis** would sound and look better. If you have more than one thesis, then you can say **theses' goals**, but again **goals of the theses** would probably be the better choice.

Comment: We can use comments to provide helpful information such as this. See also my comment above at Fraser Orr.

Answer (score 1):

Either choice could be suitable.  "Theses goals" could be perfectly acceptable as a compound.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, inanimate objects don't have 'goals'. They are the *writer's* goals, so you should phrase it differently, such as 'my goals in this thesis' or something along those lines.

So, the answer is: 'none of the above'.

Comment: This makes the incorrect assumption that ‘the goal of the thesis’ implies that the goal _belongs_ to the thesis in an actively possessing way. There is nothing wrong with saying that a thesis (or a football pitch for that matter) has a goal.